# Numpy slices vs loops

Tags: python, numpy, slice, numpy-slicing

I'm still getting my head around slices etc for arrays in python....
I have this in a loop, which works perfectly to re-scale each element of the 2D Array zMap to between 0 and "palette_size-1" (yes, I'm messing around with Fractals)... so all is good, but I think the nested loop is inefficient, so I wanted to try with slices but get this error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Here's the nested loop...

```
for x in range(self.res):
  for y in range(self.res):
     zScaled[x,y] = int((zMap[x,y] - np.amin(zMap)) * (palette_size-1) / 
                    (np.amax(zMap) - np.amin(zMap)))
```

(again, works just fine although I added the line break here for ease of reading...)
but this attempt at slices gives the aforementioned error:

```
zScaled[:,:] = int((zMap[:,:] - np.amin(zMap)) * (palette_size-1) / 
                   (np.amax(zMap) - np.amin(zMap)))
```

again added the line breaks for clarity.
Any help would be appreciated

Regards;
stuart

Comment: What's the purpose of the scalar pytbon `int`? How was `zScaled` created?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert the entire numpy array/slice into a single integer value which isn't possible. Instead you should use `astype` to let numpy do so elementwise.

Try this instead

```py
Scaled[:,:] = ((zMap[:,:] - np.amin(zMap)) * (palette_size-1) / 
                   (np.amax(zMap) - np.amin(zMap))).astype(int)
```

Comment: Also you don't need `zMap[:,:]` if you're slicing the entire array, `zMap` is adequate.

Comment: And `Scaled = ...`  No need to create an earlier array.